# \marginnote misalignment in \begin{split}

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins, marginpar, marginnote

When I use `\marginnote` in `\begin{equation}\end{equation}`, it seems to work fine, but if I try to place a margin note inside a multiline equation (at least when I use `\begin{split}\end{split}`), there is a weird extra space between the first two lines of the margin note.  I've attached a MWE so you can see what I mean.  (I made the font smaller with `\footnotesize` so it is easier to see (and also because in practice I would like the font to be the size of footnotes anyways).)
[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
3x+2 & =\marginnote{\footnotesize{The solution is $x=1$.  Blah.  Blah.  Blah.  Blah.  Blah.  Blah.}}5 \\
4y-3 & =7.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the `marginnote` before `split` (not inside). Further, as Gonzalo notes, changes to the font of marginnotes with the `marginnote` package are to be done using `\marginfont`. Also note that `\footnotesize` is a switch and it doesn't take any arguments.

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fulladjust]{marginnote}
\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\marginnote{The solution is $x=1$.  Blah.  Blah.  Blah.  Blah.  Blah.  Blah.}
\begin{split}
3x+2 & =5 \\
4y-3 & =7.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\footnotesize` doesn't take arguments. In any case, changes to the font of marginnotes with the `marginnote` package are to be done using `\marginfont`.

Comment: Well, I _can_ for a single marginnote put the command inside like done by OP (or for a set with defining a new command). `\marginfont` is useful, when I want to do this for _all_ marginnotes.

Comment: @Speravir well, the OP stated in his last sentence "I would like the font to be the size of footnotes anyways".

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Oh, I overlooked this. I was referring to “are to be done”. It’s a case of misunderstanding on my side I guess.

Comment: @Speravir It's OK. Perhaps I should've added "global changes are to be done".

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Yes, you are guilty. ;-)

Comment: The problem with this is that I plan to put more than one margin note in the `split`, and I would like the margin notes to be spaced appropriately.  Do you know how to get around this?  Do I just have to put all of them before the `split`?

Comment: @JonathanGleason: Putting them before is a good idea :)